# Getting Device Token from NSData is giving Exception

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsdata

I am getting Device token in NSData and converting it to NSString. It is printing device token correctly

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {


    deviceToken = [[devToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];



    deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


    NSLog(@"Device Token from NSdata is %@",deviceToken);


 }
```

And I am passing this from other class

```
self.Token = [AppDelegate_iPhone sharedAppDelegate].deviceToken;
```

but it is crashing on this line

```
 NSLog(@"Device Token from NSdata is %@",deviceToken);

*** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f9d00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just assigning the value to `deviceToken`. You need to retain the value otherwise it will be released right after.

```
deviceToken = [[deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] retain];
```

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:` returns an autoreleased object. If you don't want it to be released (at the end of the run loop cycle), you need to retain the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it in the past:

`const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];`
`NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description]
                                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];`

Comment: I tried this also.. Not having problem in getting device token. Having problem in using it in another class